# How to send bottom aligned background image under the fold when we resize the window height or screen size is shorter?

Tags: jquery, html, css

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/

it has an iphone image at bottom. currently when I drag browser to decrease the height background image is going towards top.

[image]

But I want it as if I resize the browser from bottom. images should not move and should go under the fold when i decrease the size of browser from bottom

like this for example

[image]

CSS

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background: url("img/iphone_34.jpg") no-repeat bottom center; }
```

Answer (score 3):

`bottom center` is keeping the bottom of the image aligned with the bottom edge of the viewport as you resize it.  So when making the window shorter, the image will move up to compensate.

<s>Try `top center` to always keep the top edge of the image aligned with the top of the viewport.</s>

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/2/)

**EDIT:**

As per further discussion with OP, the following was done using JavaScript/jQuery...

1)  Initial window height is retrieved.

2)  Image height is subtracted from window height to give the offset from the top of the window.

3)  The `background-position` of the image is fixed using jQuery `css()` with the calculated offset from the top.

4)  Resizing the window has no effect on the image's position since position is only calculated when the page initially loads.

Notes:  The code assumes it's the same image and you know its height.  The code could be altered to calculate an image's height if needed.

Original CSS placing the image is left intact as a fallback.  **Without JavaScript, image will still be placed at the bottom as in the OP's original code.**

**Full window demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/12/show/

**Code:**  http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/12/

Comment: but in the website i making i cannot align `background` to `top`. I just used this iphone image as example.

Comment: @JitendraVyas, see my updated answer.  I have a jQuery solution that meets your criteria.  Image on bottom when page initially loads and stays in same position no matter how you resize the window.

Comment: thanks for jquery solution but it's adding a vertical scroll bar see http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/6/show/

Comment: @JitendraVyas, my particular solution is not adding the vertical scroll-bar.  It's being added by the CSS in [your original JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/show/).  Simply removing `height:100%` from `body`, `html` or from both fixes it here:  [http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/7/show/](http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/7/show/).

Comment: @JitendraVyas, Your original problem and my answer have nothing to do with vertical scroll-bars.  You presented [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/) that happens to contain a vertical scroll-bar.  By applying some simple jQuery to your original code, I met your stated criteria to keep the image fixed at the bottom.  Removing the vertical scroll-bar from your [original JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMs56/) while maintaining fallback seems like a whole different problem.

Comment: I'm thankful for your effort you put into the answer. but i want add images by css not by javascript as my code is in jsfiddle. you of javascript is fine to me but images should not depend on javascript. @Lollero solution seems better suits to my needs.

Comment: @JitendraVyas, I edited my answer with a proposed fallback solution.  If JavaScript is turned off, the image will still be placed just as in your original example.

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify the vertical position in px like so:

```
body { background: url("http://digitaldaily.allthingsd.com/files/2007/06/iphone_34.jpg") no-repeat center 100px; }
```

When you use bottom it makes it relative to the page size. If you want it fixed then specify a value.

**UPDATE:**

You can also use %

All value types:

background-position: { { percentage | length | left | center | right }  1 or 2 values | inherit } ;

Comment: i want to keep the background image at bottom always.

Comment: @JitendraVyas, If you want to keep it fixed at the "bottom always", then that's how you have it now.

Comment: i know it's at bottom but when you resize the height image should go under the fold

Comment: @JitendraVyas, If you want it to go under the fold, then you have to set it at a fixed position from the top.

Comment: just add the size you want to it. Let's say you want it to stay down at 500px this will keep it there and you'll be able to scroll back up. ex: http://jsfiddle.net/pWMWy/1/

Comment: @sparky672 - i cannot set fixed height because i want to extent the layout to 100% height on any size of screen

Comment: @JitendraVyas, you would need a JavaScript solution that determines the initial height of the window in order to fix the image at that unique (different for everyone) location.

Comment: @sparky - ok if you know how we can do it by jquery please post in your answer. I'm already using jquery in project. I've added jquery tag to my question

Comment: @JitendraVyas, see my updated answer.  I have a jQuery solution that meets your criteria.  Image on bottom when page initially loads and stays in same position no matter how you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/qHNJL/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/qHNJL/4/show

HTML:

```
<!-- #hideImg and the image inside it is for getting the image height without defining a static height. -->
<div id="hideImg">
    <img src="http://digitaldaily.allthingsd.com/files/2007/06/iphone_34.jpg" alt"" />
</div>

<!-- The actual image -->
<div id="Image"></div>
```

Comment: With your solution, the image moves upward when I make the window shorter.  The OP has stated several times in various comments that he wants it to remained in a fixed position when the window is resized.

Comment: @Sparky672 Doesnt behave that way for me. Only if I have js disabled.

Comment: @Sparky672 That's strange. I tested it with FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, ie7+ and all of those worked fine. What version of Safari? Mine is Safari 5.0.5 on windows.

Comment: Safari 4 Mac but I have not encountered any discrepancies between it and Safari 5 on my other machine.

Comment: I'm seeing the same in Firefox 3.6 Mac.  Safari 5.0.6 on another machine is also the same.

Comment: @Sparky672 Judging from your answer's jsfiddle and how I now tested mine in FF 3.6.18 and Safari 5.0.5 on mac and mobile safari as well and that they all worked fine as far as I'm concerned. I think that we might not agree with what the `op` wants.

Comment: I agree... it's up to him to decide what he wants.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3807/discussion-between-lollero-and-sparky672)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal you have positioned your background "bottom center"
so it will be align to the bottom of the body try to fix it on top and you should be ok.

Comment: I cannot align to top because i want it always at bottom

Comment: This is my answer, but he does not want that.